# Swift Set Array custom sort

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, sorting

I have Contact model and I want to sort by `[firstLetter, fullName]` into `[section,row]` for UITableView in this way `"FAVORITES"` at startIndex, `"#"` at endIndex and between them are sorted letters.
For example: `["A", "C", "E", "#", "FAVORITES"]` into `["FAVORITES", "A", "C", "E", "#"]`

This is model

```
class Contact: Object {
    dynamic var fullName = ""
    dynamic var firstLetter = ""
}
```

Here's UITableViewController, where I sort data

```
class ContactsController: UITableViewController {

    // some code

    var contacts = try! Realm().objects(Contact.self).filter("isDeleted == false").sorted(by: ["firstLetter","fullName"])
    var sections: [String] {
        return Set(contacts.value(forKeyPath: "firstLetter") as![String]).sorted()
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        setUI()
    }

    // another code
}
```

**Edit #1**

---

Sorry, I forgot to say that "#" contains contacts where fullName begins with special characters

**Answer for my question**

---

```
var sections: [String] {
        return Set(contacts.value(forKeyPath: "firstLetter") as![String]).sorted {
            //Favourites sorts before all else
            if $0 == "FAVORITES" { return true }
            if $1 == "FAVORITES" { return false }

            // Symbols sort after all else
            if $0 == "#" { return false }
            if $1 == "#" { return true }

            return $0 < $1
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why not add a property isFavorite to Contact. Then have two arrays for favorites and non favorites. Sort each by letter, then concatenate them.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. What about "#", where I store contacts that starts with special character? I think it's a not good practice.

Comment: @SahandTheGreat, if you add an `isFavorite` property to `Contact`, then there's *no need* for two separate arrays, since you can just filter them like `contacts.filter{ $0.isFavorite }` or `contacts.filter{ !$0.isFavorite }`.

Comment: Why does your `Contact` store the first letter if it's already in the `fullName`?

Comment: @Alexander It's weird, but Realm doesn't support case ignorance for non-latin strings, so I convert to first letter of fullName to upperCase() to be similar for any case

Comment: @DamirShalenov So why not do that uppercasing in a computed property?

Comment: @Alexander I have to write "#" for special characters, because Realm doesn't support NSPredicate `MATCHES` for regex and I check firstLetter of fullName like `firstLetter.range(of: "^[\\p{L}\\p{M}]*$", options: .regularExpression) != nil ? firstLetter : "#"` whenever object is saved

Comment: @DamirShakenov I still don't see why `firstLetter` can't be a computed property :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I would do this. I had to change the data structure for testing purposes, but you can change it back to a class that inherits from `Object`.

```
public extension Sequence {
    public typealias Element = Iterator.Element
    public typealias Group = [Element]

    public func group<Key: Hashable>(by deriveKey: (Element) -> Key) -> [Key: Group] {
        var groups =  [Key: Group]()

        for element in self {
            let key = deriveKey(element)

            if var existingArray = groups[key] { // Group already exists for this key
                groups[key] = nil //performance optimisation to prevent CoW
                existingArray.append(element)
                groups[key] = existingArray
            }
            else {
                groups[key] = [element] // Create new group
            }
        }

        return groups
    }
}


struct Contact: CustomStringConvertible {
    let fullName: String
    let isFavourte: Bool

    var firstLetter: Character {
        return fullName.characters.first!
    }

    var containsSpecialLetters: Bool {
        return false // implement me
    }

    init(_ fullName: String, _ isFavourte: Bool) {
        self.fullName = fullName
        self.isFavourte = isFavourte
    }

    var description: String { return fullName }
}

let contacts = [
    Contact("Alice", false),
    Contact("Alex", false),
    Contact("Bob", true),
    Contact("Bill", false),
    Contact("Cory", false),
    Contact("Casey", true),
    Contact("#åœ∑´ß", false),
    Contact("D", false),
    Contact("E", false),
    Contact("F", false),
    Contact("G", false),
    Contact("H", false),
]


let sections = contacts.group{ contact -> String in
    switch contact {
        case _ where contact.isFavourte: return "Favourites"
        case _ where contact.containsSpecialLetters: return "#"
        case _: return String(contact.firstLetter)
    }
}

let sectionHeaders = sections.keys.sorted {
    //Favourites sorts before all else
    if $0 == "Favourites" { return true }
    if $1 == "Favourites" { return false }

    // Symbols sort after all else
    if $0 == "#" { return false }
    if $1 == "#" { return true }

    return $0 < $1
}

for (sectionHeader, sectionContacts) in sectionHeaders.map({($0, sections[$0]!)}) {
    print("===== \(sectionHeader) =====")
    sectionContacts.forEach{ print($0) }
}
```

Output:

> ===== Favourites =====
>
> Bob
>
> Casey
>
> ===== A =====
>
> Alice
>
> Alex
>
> ===== B =====
>
> Bill
>
> ===== C =====
>
> Cory
>
> ===== D =====
>
> D
>
> ===== E =====
>
> E
>
> ===== F =====
>
> F
>
> ===== G =====
>
> G
>
> ===== H =====
>
> H
>
> ===== # =====
>
> åœ∑´ß

Comment: Thanks for answer! I just used one function from your code `sections.keys.sorted{}`.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you are trying to do, you may first retrieve your favorites and sort them.

Then you retrieve those starting with #.

After that you retrieve the rest and sort them.

At that point you just append the third set, and then the second, to the "favorites" array.

So the result will be an [Contact] with FAVORITES first then contacts starting with A, with B, etc., and finally those starting with #

I assume you already have the contacts, since I've never used Realm.io and that your contacts or your table do have an isFavorite flag.

Pseudo code:

```
func sortContacts(_ aList: [Contact]) -> [Contact]
{
    var retValue = [Contact]()

    var favorites = Set(aList.value(forKeyPath: "isFavorite == true") as![String]).sorted()

    var theRest = Set(aList.value(forKeyPath: "firstLetter") as![String]).sorted()

    retValue.append(favorites)
    retValue.append(theRest)

    return retValue
}
```

and you should call it in viewWillAppear for example as:

```
func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool)
{
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    sections = sortContacts(contacts)

    // code
}
```

Comment: I modified my answer with a pseudocode @DamirShakenov